# Many video players(Hls.js) - how to improve performance

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming

I have a dashboard on which I run at least 5 videos at the same time using HLS (Hls.js). The problem is that the utilization of resources is very high, so the performance of the site is not the best(~50% CPU). Is there a way to optimize this ?

Comment: Use lower qualities for the the streams and use fMP4 so you don't need to transmux the MPEG 2 transport stream to mp4.

Comment: Are there any other tips for increasing performace on 2022? Is fmp4 now enabled by default?

Answer (score 0):

Switch to fMP4, it is mandatory for decreasing CPU usage with hlsjs.

We are using it in our flussonic for client-side mosaic and can put up to 16 players on single page.